# TYPO3 submit fluid variable to typoscript to prefill powermail field

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, powermail

I try to submit a variable from fluid to typoscript, to use it to prefill a powermail field.
I need this value, but it could not be rendered by database.

I tried the following, but the value will not send to the prefill text.

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.getCurrentEventDate" data="{mydate: '{event.date ->f:format.date(format=\'%d.%m.%Y\')}'}"/>
```

In Typoscript I have:

```
lib.getCurrentEventDate = TEXT
lib.getCurrentEventDate {
     10 = TEXT
     10.field = mydate
     10.data = {mydate}
     10.wrap = TESTerer: |
     10.insertData = 1 
}
```

For powermail prefill:

```
    plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill {
        dateField = TEXT
        dateField < lib.getCurrentEventDate
    }
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible this way. You could use a userfunc in lib. getCurrentEventDate to get the data somehow.